# Is it possible to serialise the data returned by method in Gson like JSP does?

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Just to set the context, In JSP, we can access a method of an object as follows.

```
Class Student

 public Object getXXXWhichNeedsFewLogic() {
    // Logic to get obj, which i don't want to store as a variable in this class.
    return obj;
}
```

If we pass student object to jsp, we can access this method like

> student.XXXWhichNeedsFewLogic

Is it possible to achieve the same during Gson serialization? Final output json should contain the value as

> { XXXWhichNeedsFewLogic : obj }

Comment: *If we pass student object to jsp, we can access this method like* are you talking about JSTL?

Comment: tried to check [the docs](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)? perhaps you could start from custom serializer.

Comment: @Scary Wombat: Yes i was talking about JSTL.

Comment: Yes thank @Bagus Tesa. That worked.

Comment: glad you worked it out, anyway, why don't you write your own answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a sample class for serializing results from a method.

```
public class GsonTest {

public static class Student {
    public Object getXXXWhichNeedsFewLogic() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

public static class GetterSerializer<T> implements JsonSerializer<T> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(T src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if (null == src) {
            return new JsonNull();
        }
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        for (Method m : src.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && m.getParameterCount() == 0) {
                try {
                    obj.add(m.getName().substring(3), context.serialize(m.invoke(src)));
                } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
@Test
public void testSerialization() {
    System.out.println(
            new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, new GetterSerializer<Student>())
                    .create()
                    .toJson(new Student()));
}
```